# Check if a string has unique characters excluding whitespace

Tags: python, string

I'm practicing questions from Cracking the coding interview to become better and just in case, be prepared. The first problem states: Find if a string has all unique characters or not? I wrote this and it works perfectly:

```
def isunique(string):
    x = []
    for i in string:
        if i in x:
            return False
        else:
            x.append(i)
    return True
```

Now, my question is, what if I have all unique characters like in:
**'I am J'**
which would be pretty rare, but lets say it occurs by mere chance, how can I create an exception for the spaces? I a way it doesn't count the space as a character, so the func returns True and not False?

Comment: use `isspace()`

Comment: I would suggest just running `string.replace(" ", "")` before passing it into your already working `isunique` function...

Comment: @mentalita how exactly would you incorporate isspace()? beacuse if I do it in the for loop, it makes the string a bool and not iterable

Comment: @MauricioCastaneda: what? how does `isspace()` make the string a bool? lol

Comment: @mentalita I tried doing it this way, for i in string.isspace():, and then python gave me an error saying: 'bool' object is not iterable, that's why I asked how would you implement if with isspace()?

Comment: @MauricioCastaneda:  `if i in x and not i.isspace(): ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now no matter how space or how many special characters in your string , it will just count the words :

```
import re
def isunique(string):
    pattern=r'\w'
    search=re.findall(pattern,string)
    string=search
    x = []
    for i in string:
        if i in x:
            return False
        else:
            x.append(i)
    return True



print(isunique('I am J'))
```

output:

```
True
```

without space words test case :

```
print(isunique('war'))
True
```

with  space words test case:

```
print(isunique('w a r'))
True
```

repeating letters :

```
print(isunique('warrior'))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant approach (YMMV), with `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

def isunique(string):
    return Counter(string.replace(' ', '')).most_common(1)[0][-1] == 1
```

---

Alternatively, if your strings contain more than just whitespaces (tabs and newlines for instance), I'd recommend regex based substitution:

```
import re
string = re.sub(r'\s+', '', string, flags=re.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of characters you want to consider as non-characters and replace them in string. Then perform your function code.

As an alternative, to check the uniqueness of characters, the better approach will be to compare the length of final string with the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) value of that string as:

```
def isunique(my_string):
    nonchars = [' ', '.', ',']
    for nonchar in nonchars:
        my_string = my_string.replace(nonchar, '')
    return len(set(my_string)) == len(my_string)
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> isunique( 'I am J' )
True
```

---

As per the Python's [`set() document`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set):

> Return a new set object, optionally with elements taken from iterable.
>   set is a built-in class. See set and Set Types — set, frozenset for
>   documentation about this class.

Answer (score 0):

And... a pool of answers is never complete unless there is also a regex solution:

```
def is_unique(string):
    import re
    patt = re.compile(r"^.*?(.).*?(\1).*$")
    return not re.search(patt, string)
```

(I'll leave the whitespace handling as an exercise to the OP)

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution

```
def isunique(string):
    return all(string.count(i)==1 for i in string if i!=' ')
```

Comment: Simple != best. This function has quadratic complexity, and is really slow.